# Simplifying an expression with $\Delta$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Let $\sum_j\chi_j(x)^2=1$ be a partition of unity with respect to the variable $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2d}$.
Please help me to simplify as possible

$$\sum_j\langle \chi_ju,-\Delta(\chi_ju)\rangle-\langle u,-\Delta u\rangle$$

for all $u\in\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the question is interesting, since it reminds me of the techniques of paradifferential calculus: however, could you provide a little more context, i.e. why this problem is interesting for you and if you tried something?

Comment: this is what i wrote but i don't know if it is true and if so how to continu: $$\sum_j\langle \chi_ju,-\Delta(\chi_ju)\rangle-\langle u,-\Delta u\rangle=\sum_j\langle \nabla(\chi_ju),\nabla(\chi_ju)\rangle-\langle u,-\Delta u\rangle=\sum_j\langle \nabla(\chi_j)u+\nabla(u)\chi_j, \nabla(\chi_j)u+\nabla(u)\chi_j\rangle-\langle u,-\Delta u\rangle=\sum_j\langle \nabla(\chi_j)u, \nabla(\chi_j)u\rangle+\sum_j\langle \nabla(u)\chi_j,\nabla(u)\chi_j\rangle+\sum_j\langle \nabla(\chi_j)u, \nabla(u)\chi_j\rangle+\sum_j\langle \nabla(u)\chi_j, \nabla(\chi_j)u\rangle-\langle u,-\Delta u\rangle$$

Comment: $\Delta$ is what? The Laplace operator? What is the scalar product you are using? $C_0^\infty$ refers to smooth functions with compact support or vanishing at infinity? I imagine the first so you can view the space as embedded in $L^2$ and get your scalar product that way.

Comment: @s.harp, $\Delta$ is The Laplace operator, the scalar product is in $L^2$, C∞0  refers to smooth functions with compact support

Comment: Compact support would be denoted by $C_c^\infty$.

Comment: @ André S, ok i am sorry